# Php upgrade - Definitely export the path?

Tags: php, macos, apache

How can I definitely export php on my setup ?
Whenever I open a new console and show the php version, php 5.6 is provide.
So I've to execute this commande :

```
 export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH;
```

More than this is stupid, It prevent my task scheduler to work.

My operating system is macOS Sierra.

Comment: Try to find a file named .profile or .bashrc (linux), and then append your line of code at the bottom. This is useful for finding profile configuration on mac: https://superuser.com/questions/147043/where-to-find-the-bashrc-file-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-and-lion

Comment: Thanks ! I've found it on /etc, but he was not hidden. That seems to work.

Comment: Great, glad you have sort it out, there is one more thing, you must reload the profile (linux cli cmnd: source ~/.bashrc ) or restart the cli, cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately the task scheduler still provide by php 5.6...
edit : I try that

Comment: Scheduler continues not to take it into account.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the symlink to the php version that you want to use

```
which php -> /usr/bin/php
ls -la /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives (this is on linux)
```

on mac would be something with cellar in the path, I don't remember now

After you find the right php executable that you want to use, php7.0, you can remove the symlink and add the new one

```
ln -s /path/to/php/executable /usr/bin/php
```

please check the right paths since now I am not on the mac

Comment: I'm looking for the php7 executable

Comment: But I think this is the problem because if I execute him in this file : 
./php -v 
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb  7 2017 16:06:52)